# Apache2 on Raspberry Pi: 403 Forbidden after changing web root/chown not working

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

So I'm pretty new to servers; I've been running websites off of 3rd party hosts, but I thought I might like to try it on my own for once.  I got a Raspberry Pi running Raspian Wheezy, and I successfully installed Apache2.

When I tested Apache for the first time before modifying any settings, it returned the "Everything is working fine!" message.  However, I have an external USB drive that I wanted my webroot to reside on.  I went into the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default, and changed the DocumentRoot and Directory from /var/www/ to the following address that specifies a folder I made in my mounted device.

```
    DocumentRoot /media/888F-2455/www/
    <Directory /media/888F-2455/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

When I tried to load my localhost again, I was met with a 403 forbidden error.  After doing some looking around, it seemed that taking ownership of the folder would solve this problem.  I tried inputting `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/888F-2455/www` into my root terminal, but I was told

```
chown: changing ownership of `/media/888F-2455/www/index.html': Operation not permitted
```

Which I can't understand since I'm a root user using the root terminal.

What is going on here and how can I fix it?  Please answer like you're talking to an 8 year old because I'm not very adept at linux or apache at this point in time.

Comment: You shouldn't give a webserver write access. Just make the files in question readable by the webserver using something like `chmod -R a+r /media/888F-2455/www`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message usually indicates the filesystem is in read only mode or not fully supported.

Please check the following:

- which filesystem is the external drive formated with? (**mount| grep media**)
- is the drive mounted rw (same as above)

If the external drive is formated with fat/fat32/ntfs this is your problem.

If not then unmount the drive (do not unplug it), run a filesystem check and mount again explicitly specifying rw (mount -o noatime,rw /dev/... /media/..)

Comment: i figured this out last night, it was the filesystem.  after i reformatted to ext4 it was all good